Bound probability that new observation exceeds $k$th largest
Let $X, X_1, \dots, X_n$ denote i.i.d. random variables. Reorder $X_1, \dots, X_n$ into $X_{(1)}, \dots, X_{(n)}$ such that
$$
X_{(1)} \geq X_{(2)} \geq \dots \geq X_{(n)}.
$$
For $k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$, I want to determine whether
$$
\mathbb{P}(X > X_{(k)}) \leq \frac{k}{n+1}.
$$
I believe there should be equality when the probability of ties in $X_1, \dots, X_n$ is zero although I care less about this. Can we show this inequality?
I'm hoping for a nice symmetry-based argument but the fact that ties can occur in this setup complicates things. Any thoughts?
